# How do I keep GUI elements on top of a movie playing via code in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a storyboard. In my viewDidLoad I can show and play my movie, but any buttons on the storyboard are hidden. I can add them in code, but would prefer my graphic elements to be laid out on my storyboard and have them sit on top of the movie.  Suggestions most appreciated. Code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"mov"];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

  moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                             object:moviePlayer];

  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f);
  }

  moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

  [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

  moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

  moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

  [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

  [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

  [self.moviePlayer play];

  // manually can add buttons here, but prefer not too it in code

  UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(aMethod:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

  myButton.frame = CGRectMake(26.0, 585.0, 474.0, 87.0);
  myButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
  [myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:35]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Created new layer. Simple.